# How to collect a urine sample from a house rabbit?

Tags: health, rabbits

"Bring your rabbit in with a urine sample" says the vet.  On occasion when we have been in to the vets, he is able to get a sample by holding the bunny and pushing on the bladder, while someone holds a cup and catches the stream.  It does not always work for the vet; and I hesitant to try it home, as I have no idea what the right amount of pressure is.

My rabbits are litter box trained.  I am pretty sure abunch of wet sawdust as the sample is not going to be a good idea.

If I leave the bunny in a carrier long enough they will eventially pee, not sure I can wringout a sample from a towel.  If it lands on the carrier floor (plastic) the bunny is likely to get all wet with little left to pour into a container.  I am also not keen on the psychological trauma, this would induce.

Looking for ideas, how to accomplish getting a urine sample from my rabbit.

Comment: How sensitive to litter changes are rabbits?  That is, if you used something other than your usual in the box for a day or two, would your bun freak or just shrug?

Comment: @MonicaCellio it is more about location then filler, for rabbits potty habits.

Comment: Ok, I don't have time to pursue this now (so consider it a tip for anyone else who wants to run with it, but I've seen my vet use (for cats) a non-absorbent litter alternative in the box -- so the cat goes and then you can basically pour off the urine (or strain the pellets).

Comment: I doubt there were be too much Psych trauma with getting pee on their paws...

Comment: @Chad, I was talking about keeping them locked in carrier until the pee.  Kind of like locking a person in the closet until they can't hold it anymore.  Not pleasant.

Comment: Oh yeah most my rabbits do not like to pee when they are in their carriers anyway.  Much better to put them someplace they feel comfortable and let them relax.  But rabbits are not as complex thinking as humans are.  Many of them are actually quite comfortable in small confined spaces for relatively short periods(Mine handle a full day just fine).

Comment: With a little searching on the hint from @MonicaCellio I found 'safflower seed litter box' seems to be possible solution. Still looking into considerations with a bunny, but found at least one rabbit food with safflower seed as an ingredient.  Will they eat it, if so how much and is that bad.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, see [new question](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2199) related to your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This suggestion is from one of the members or our local pet bunny community, she has used it with good results.

Fill your litter box with clean litter and cover the litter with a light plastic wrap (like [saran wrap](http://www.saranbrands.com/)).  The bunny will use the litter box like normal, but it will leave a puddle.  Use a sterile syringe to collect the urine as soon as they hop out.

Answer (score 5):

I would put the rabbit in it cage and confine it with some water, every 10 to 15 minutes try to pick it up and express some urine.

For me I find it easiest to hold them so their body is vertical. Then apply firm pressure to the belly.  If the rabbit has to pee this pressure will be enough to trigger it to release.  It is best to have someone hold a cup over the area to collect the urine.    The pressure should not be so much as to cause damage but nice firm pressure with the flat of you hand.  If the rabbit does not pee repeat the process.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll borrow Monica's idea and say: **fill the rabbits litter tray with fish tank gravel** (you probably want to wash the gravel first).  Then just pour the pee out.

Comment: The problem is then you risk introducing contaminants that make it look like your bunny is sick but it was just from the gravel... even washed gravel can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a combination of the three answers provided with a slight twist.  My rabbit is somewhat handicapped his front legs do not work with maybe 50% function in one and 25% in the other. We have a wire bottom (*1/2 inch mesh*) cage that we use when traveling long distances in the car. It has a tray underneath, it is old but in good repair and clean.

I placed some litter in the bottom of the tray to make an uneven surface and then covered it with plastic wrap (*saran wrap*). At 8AM I put him in the cage with hay, water and a salt lick. 10AM he still had not urinated. I tired to express some urine, no luck.  Noon he still had not urinated. I tired to express some urine, no luck. He is not drinking much. Gave him a big bowl of lettuce, he eats the lettuce.  2PM he finally urinates!

I used a syringe to suck the urine from the puddles on the plastic wrap. Placed the urine filled syringe in plastic bag in the refrigerator until the evening vet visit.  Lab tests seemed fine (minor fluctuations in line with his health issues).