# What to pour on soil where cats eliminate?

Tags: cats, health

I have a small plot of land (about 10x10 feet) with soil and a few trees. I also take care of  5-7 street kitties and this is where they pee and poop.

Is there anything I can pour on this soil to “neutralize” the cats’ waste? They will continue peeing and pooping in the area, but it would be great to add something to the soil that will “manage” all of this cat waste.

By the way, they cover up their stuff pretty well, so they’re doing their part.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to "neutralize" the waste? Do you have a problem with the smell or pests or do you just feel like you should do *something* without being sure why?

Comment: i think it is best to make another area where the cats can do their stuff,for ideas about what you can use take a look here https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18298/what-types-of-kitty-litter-are-there-and-what-else-can-be-used-as-kitty-litter

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use some kind of  'bio-enzymatic cleaning agent' like [Nature's Miracle](http://www.naturesmiracle.com/products/cat.aspx) the enzymes neutralize the waste.

Look for a product without perfumes. Most of these products work best when moist or wet, so you may need to spray water on the area regularly both to help neutralize and to dilute.