# Is there a difference between the super scoop, double duty and multi-cat litters?

Tags: cats, cat-litter

I went to a pet superstore recently searching for clumping clay litter, and they only sell cat litter from two different companies... let's call them CompanyA and CompanyB.

Even though these two companies only sell clumping clay litter at this particular store, they have several "varieties". For example, CompanyA has *Super Scoop*, *Double Duty*, and Multi-Cat. CompanyB has *MULTI-CAT*, *EXTREME*, and *TRIPLE ACTION*.

I've seen these "differences" in other cat litter before, but I have no idea what the differences are.

With that said, I have two cats: one's middle-aged and the other one's a senior citizen.

Is there a difference between these "varieties" of cat litter?

For example, the *Super Scoop* and *Double Duty* from CompanyA are apparently heavy-duty cat litters, so why do they offer a *Multi-Cat*?

CompanyB has *TRIPLE ACTION* which sounds like something from a Rambo movie, but is it stronger than *EXTREME*? Will *TRIPLE ACTION* and *EXTREME* not work if it recognizes that there is different feces from different cats and that's why they offer *MULTI-CAT*?

Comment: giving advice about what product to buy is off topic here so you should edit the what to buy part out of your question.for questions about a spesific brand you will find this on their web page.here is a little information about different types of cat litter https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18298/what-types-of-kitty-litter-are-there-and-what-else-can-be-used-as-kitty-litter

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: It's all marketing speak. None of these are "universal standards," they're just words slapped on a package to influence your purchase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience the names of the different litters make no difference.
As Allison has pointed out it is mostly marketing logic.
You can use any litter for several cats, I for my part have two cats and never bought (nor seen) any multi-cat litter.

Where it is really at is clump or no clump, which material it is and whether it is scented.

I think the best thing you can do is to offer two different ones in two boxes and see if they maybe prefer one.

As an example you might be able to compare it to human products like deodorant.
There might be SPORTY, SWEAT FREE, SUPER LONG and such, and they might be minimally different, but really they all get the job done.

Comment: In some cases, multi-cat can actually be WORSE than regular; I never buy the multi-cat formulation of the litter I use, because it does nothing at all for odor control and turns into sludge, while the "single cat" version clumps hard and doesn't stink.